# Complexity of the ellipsoid method in general convex problems

Tags: reference-request, convex-optimization, computational-complexity

The ellipsoid method is often mentioned in relation to the complexity of solving linear programs.
Is the method however polynomial in the general non-linear convex cases? Preferably I would like a reference to a work stating the complexity of the method in such cases.

Note: I had a look at [this](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/1423/why-is-the-ellipsoid-method-of-polynomial-complexity) question, but could not find what I am looking for.

Comment: Not all convex problems can be solved in polynomial time to best of my knowledge. I mean there can be a convex function that cannot be evaluated in polynomial time. See also co-positive programming.

Comment: @ErlingMOSEK Yeah, that Copositive Programming is funky stuff . 2011 book chapter on Copositive Programming by Sam Burer https://sburer.github.io/papers/033-cpchap.pdf  in https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4614-0769-0_8

Answer (score 0):

The following links refers to application of ellipsoidal algorithms with some variations to NLPs:

[Paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0305054803000455) by Drs. Rugenstein. E & Kupferschimd.M: presents results showing convergence by ellipsoidal algorithm to convex NLPs

[Lecture notes from Univ of British Columbia](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Enickhar/W13/Lecture4.pdf): application of ellipsoids with separation Oracle method for nonlinear objective

Also helpful lecture notes from [Georgia Tech](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/%7Enemirovs/InteriorPointalgorithmsforConvexProgrammingNestrov&Nemirovski2001.pdf): discussion on Dr. N.Karmakar's interior points methods.

Comment: But what is the runtime complexity of the ellipsoid method in this case?

Comment: The first paper gives an indication using cpu time.

Comment: I read the first paper. They report cpu time in simulation experiments, but do not provide a theoretic guarantee for the run-time